# Why, all of a sudden, do I have to push GIT to see my CSS changes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, heroku

My technology is a simple Javascript/Node.js app deployed through git with Heroku. (No external frameworks or packages)

I've been working on my project smoothly for a few days in this environment now on my localhost. And all of a sudden, my CSS changes don't update unless I commit, and then push the git??

This hasn't always been the case. I feel like something I did changed a setting somewhere? I don't know what code to post to demonstrate? I was hoping these clues might tip somebody off to what I may have done to cause this?

It sounds like a caching thing, but I've cleared browser data and all caches multiple times, and tried 2 different browsers...and don't know what else to do to troubleshoot this one?

Committing and pushing git to see every CSS change isn't working for me.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: My guess is that instead of looking at `http(s)://localhost` you're looking at `https://somewhere.else`.

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out.  It was an issue toggling between my staging ENV and my production ENV. The static assets were pointed to the wrong dir on localhost while running in the production ENVironment. So, to run locally, I run the app: NODE_ENV=staging blah blah